# TFS 2015 update 2 : Customize task board cards in the process template

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

I'm trying to customize a process template in TFS 2015 update 2 so when I create a new team project, my task board is setup as we want it in our team. So far, by editing the *processconfiguration.xml* file, I've been able to add the required columns in the task board but now, I want to setup the fields that appear on the cards (like I can do using the configuration screen bellow).

Do anyone know if (and where) I can set that information so every new Team Project I'll create with that template will have the task board setup properly ?

Thanks

[image: Task board configuration window]

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom field， you need to edit the WIT definition to add a **FIELD** element within the **FIELDS** section and a **Control** element within the **FORM** section. More detail steps please refer the link from MSDN:[Add or modify a field](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-field)--*To add a custom field*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the informations but I know all that. My question is related to the field appearing on the task board cards, not on the work item form. Unless you tell me there's a kind of "control" that specifies that the field must appear on the card ? Thanks